# Why does giving ":/Icons/controller.png" to a constructor work (is that valid relative filepath syntax)?

Tags: c++, file, filepath

The details of the situation don't matter, but in particular I'm making a QIcon object (part of the Qt library) out of a .png file. The constructor for this takes a string that should be a filepath

I find that, instead of using an absolute path, I can simply give something like `":/Icons/controller.png"` to the constructor and the icon is still correctly retrieved and displayed.

My project is huge so I won't write out the hierarchy and where the file is relative to everything else, but they're at 3 degrees of separation at least. Because of this I think there's some sort of file searching mechanic that I don't know of. Can anyone guess what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:/` paths are paths in the [Qt Resource System](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html).

You have a QRC file that is compiled and bundled with your executable. It references the images.

E.g. your qrc file contains this:

```
<RCC version="1.0">
    <qresource>
        <file>Icons/controller.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

This is then compiled in your build process with the RCC compiler. This file is then linked with your exe.

The default resources are automatically registered, but you can also compile resources into external RCC bundles, and load them at runtime using `QResource::registerResource("/path/to/myresource.rcc");`

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps immensely! An unrelated question that came to mind when considering the details you pointed out: at where/how is the linker instructed to include the compiled QRC file with your program? Is that something Qt handles for you?

Comment: AFAIR, rcc compiles to a c++ source file (using `static char[]` for the assets), and this is then compiled to an object,and linked into your program; or you simply `#include` that file in one of your own c++ files. How all this is invoked depends on your IDE / build system. qmake does all this under the hood